# Qgis: How to export polygon shapefile with coordinates in degrees

Tags: shapefile, qgis, coordinate-systems

I am new to Qgis. I am trying to export a shapefile of polygons so that I can read its vertices can be read (e.g. by python packages like fiona or shapely) as lat and lon coordinates in degrees. What I am getting now are coordinates in meters.
I am using a EPSG:4326 projected coordinate reference system, though I could change that.
Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may open your layer in tabular form (press F6) and copy-paste (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V) all features into excel. There (usually, in the first column) you might notice your geometries in WKT (well-known text) format - every vertex is shown in form of decimal degree coordinates.

Alternatively, you may use field calculator (button  [image]) and create new text field of 0 length (no length limitations) with `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` in 'Expression'. So that, explicit wkt representation of your geometries will be present in each feature attributes. From there you may export your layer to csv-file, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, this helped (sorry I only had time to check now).